# timepicker jquery plugin questions

Tags: jquery, timepicker

This question is for people who have used trent richardson's jquery timepicker jquery before. I have 2 questions:

question 1: How can I remove the "Now" button as I do not need this button

question 2: is there are way I can move the slider slightly further away from the Hours, Minutes and seconds text as the slider button overlaps part of the word "Mintues" and "Seconds" everytime I open up the timepicker and the slider button appears at the start?

Trent Richardson's jquery timepicker plugin can be seen on this website, click [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (It shows datepicker and timepicker at start of website but if you move further down the page it only displays the timepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a quick peruse through his js file on github and it looks like other than a hack job to the js file you wont be able to remove the now button. And with the 2nd one it seems like you might have to do the same where you make a custom change to the css and js file to change the layout of the popup.

Comment: I forgot to mention is there a way I can format the time from 00:00:00 to 00 hrs 00 mins 00 secs?

Comment: pretty much the same thing gonna need to go in and change some stuff with the js file